# Node.js Facebook Logout with (force = true) not working

Tags: facebook, hello.js

I'm using hello.js to login/logout facebook (wiht Vue-cli and Quasar-cli)
    I assign the value "true" to the parameter "force" to the user will be logged out of the provider site as well as the local application, but the connection to the provider keeps on.
    Relevant code:

```
- hello.js:

import hello from 'hellojs'
export default ({ Vue }) => {
    hello.init({
        facebook: '123412341234123'
    })
    Vue.prototype.$hello = hello
}


- logout.vue

  ...

<q-btn
    color="primary" glossy push class="full-width"
    icon="fab fa-facebook-f" label="Terminar sessão"
    size="md" @click="logout_auth('facebook')" >
</q-btn>

...

logout (network) {
    this.$hello.logout(network, true).then(function (json) {
        var obj = JSON.stringify(json)
        console.log('logout OK: ' + obj)
    }, function (e) {
    console.log('logout error: ' + e.error.message)
    })
}


any help will be appreciated.
```

Comment: AFAIK you can only log out of Facebook from your app, if the user logged in to Facebook specifically to login to your site/app. If they were logged in to Facebook before already, then they are not supposed to be logged out of that.

Comment: thanks for answering
Yes, I read about it. I login in the same site, 2 buttons "login" and "logout"
The login opens the facebook login window

Comment: - logout.vue
 `
 ...
 <q-btn
   color="primary" glossy push class="full-width"
   icon="fab fa-facebook-f" label="Login with facebook"
   size="md" @click="auth('facebook')" >
 </q-btn>

 ...

    auth (network) {
      this.$hello(network).login().then(function (json) {
        var obj = JSON.stringify(json)
        console.log('json: ' + obj + ':fim json')
 
      }, function (e) {
        console.log('auth error: ' + e.error.message)
      })
    } 
 `

Comment: Yeah, but were you logged in to Facebook before already, or not?

Comment: No, I logout facebook first, and login with my hello.js code. When execute the logout code, the local connection is closed but the provider conection not

Comment: I guess this uses FB.logout internally(?), so it should work as described under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/ If it doesn’t, that is probably a Facebook issue then.

Comment: Thaks, I'll search this way.

Comment: I found the solution
The 'network' shall be in 'hello' and in 'logout' put the 'force' object, like this:

this.$hello(network).logout({ force: true }).then(function (json) {

Note there are a sepace before the 'true' value.
I hope this will be useful for someone